# Ping failed to second ip in openstack instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, rdo

I have  RDO openstack environment in a machine for testing. The RDO was installed with `packstack --allinone` command. Using HOT I have created two instances. One with `cirros` image and another with `Fedora`. The `Fedora` instance have two interfaces that are connected to same network while `cirros` have only one interface and connected to same network. The template looks like this -

```
heat_template_version: 2015-10-15
description: Simple template to deploy two compute instances

resources:

   local_net:
     type: OS::Neutron::Net

   local_signalling_subnet:
     type: OS::Neutron::Subnet
     properties:
       network_id: { get_resource: local_net }
       cidr: "50.0.0.0/24"
       ip_version: 4

   fed:
     type: OS::Nova::Server
     properties:
     image: fedora
     flavor: m1.small
     key_name: heat_key
     networks:
        - network: local_net
     networks:
        - port: { get_resource: fed_port1 }
        - port: { get_resource: fed_port2 }

   fed_port1:
     type: OS::Neutron::Port
     properties:
      network_id: { get_resource: local_net }

  fed_port2:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:
      network_id: { get_resource: local_net }

  cirr:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
       image: cirros
       flavor: m1.tiny
       key_name: heat_key
    networks:
       - network: local_net
    networks:
       - port: { get_resource: cirr_port }

 cirr_port:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:
      network_id: { get_resource: local_net }
```

The Fedora instance got two ips (50.0.0.3 and 50.0.0.4). Cirros got ip 50.0.0.5. I can ping 50.0.0.3 from `cirros` instance but not the ip 50.0.0.4. If I manually down the interface with ip 50.0.0.3 in the `Fedora` instance, then only I can ping 50.0.0.4 from `cirros` instance. Is there a restriction in the configuration of neutron that prohibits ping to both the ips of `Fedora` instance at same time. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the default firewall-ing done by OpenStack networking (neutron) -- it simply drops any packets received on a port if the source address of the packet does not match the IP address assigned to the port.

When cirros instance sends ping packet to 50.0.0.4, fedora instance receives it on the interface with IP address 50.0.0.4. However, when it is responding back to cirros's IP address 50.0.0.5, the linux networking stack on your fedora machine has two interfaces to choose from to send out the response (because both those interfaces are connected to the same network). In your case, fedora choose to respond back on on 50.0.0.3. However, the source IP address in the packet is still 50.0.0.4, and thus the OpenStack networking layer simply drops it.

General recommendation is to not have multiple interfaces on the same network. If you want multiple IP addresses from the same network for your VM, you can use "fixed_ips" option in your heat template:

```
fed_port1:
  type: OS::Neutron::Port
  properties:
    network_id: { get_resource: local_net }
    fixed_ips:
    - ip_address: "50.0.0.4"
    - ip_address: "50.0.0.3"
```

Since DHCP server would offer only IP address, fedora would be configured with only one IP. You can add another IP to your interface using "ip addr add" command (see http://www.unixwerk.eu/linux/redhat/ipalias.html):

```
ip addr add 50.0.0.3/24 brd + dev eth0 label eth0:0
```

Comment: Following your suggestion I have tried to add two fixed ips in `fedora` instance. But even doing so, the `ip addr` command shows only one ip in `fedora` and ping from `cirros` also succeeds for only one ip.

Comment: On each interface, only one IP is offered by the DHCP server in neutron and hence only one IP will be configured by default. You can add another ip address to your interface in fedora by using "ip addr add" command. See [link](http://www.unixwerk.eu/linux/redhat/ipalias.html): `ip addr add 50.0.0.4/24 brd + dev eth0 label eth0:0`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Your solution worked like charm. Thanks